# How to write Debian to a USB flash drive from a Debian live CD?

Tags: linux, command-line, livecd, liveusb

I’m new to Linux, and I want to create a live USB flash drive for Debian Jessie. I burned Debian to a CD in order to then create a live USB flash drive of it.

Win32DiskManager doesn’t download due to a malware warning, so I’m trying to create the live USB flash drive with the terminal in Debian.

I copied the ISO image to the live desktop and tried to create the USB flash drive with:

```
cp xxxx /dev/sdb1
```

Where `xxxx` is the Debian ISO image.

When I navigate to the desktop with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

I get the error:

> cp: cannot create regular file '/dev/sdb1': Permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to do it is to download Rufus in Windows from the [official Rufus website](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Rufus is the recommended application at the official [Ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for making a bootable live Ubuntu USB on Windows, and it also works for making live USBs of many of other Linux distributions including Debian.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear where you got this command from:

```
cp xxxx /dev/sdb1
```

But one of two issues I can deduce from your use of that command.

1. First, the `cp` command alone would not ever work for a situation like this. It would just copy the files to the destination but not in a way that would make it bootable.
2. Are you 100% sure you know the USB device is mounted as `/dev/sdb1`?
3. You need to run a command like that to write to a device as root or via `sudo`. But like I said, `cp` would not work for a task like this.

The command you should be using to handle a task like this is [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd). And the command would be something like this:

```
sudo dd if=/path/of/the/CD/ISO of=/path/of/the/destination/USB bs=1024
```

The `if` is the “input file” and the `of` “output file” so the whole command is just copying the raw data from the CD disk to the USB flash drive. The `bs` is just the read/write byte size of how much data would be written at a time. And note you should be doing this kind of operation using root privileges via `sudo` if you are not actually logged in a root.

But the real key here is now trying to figure out the actual USB device ID for the USB device. If you are 100% sure that `/dev/sdb1` is the correct device path, then go for it. But in the end you might want to double-check which device is the USB device by using [`lsblk`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsblk) (list block devices) just like this:

```
lsblk
```

And deduce the USB flash drive device path from that. Or even just use `fdisk` like this to show a list of all connected and mounted devices:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Once you are 100% positive of what the actual device path is, use that.

Comment: I was using the Debian FAQ https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb and I made the mistake of assuming that a "Linux machine" was the same as a live CD.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but @karel's solution solved my in that now the live usb works. But thanks for the instructions. They'll come in handy later.